# How to return 1 in numpy array with one row using .shape?

Tags: python, numpy

For the arrays with only one row `x_data.shape` return `(4,)` or `(5,)` is it possible to modify it to return `(4,1)`? Sometimes when I pass one dimension matrix to my function it runs into an error because `m = x_data.shape[1]` is not defined.

Comment: Do you want a shape of `(4, 1)` (one column) or `(1, 4)` (one row)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`expand_dims()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html) NumPy function:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
print(a.shape)  # (4,)
a = np.expand_dims(a, 1)
print(a.shape)  # (4, 1)
print(a)  # column vector
```

Note that `(4, 1)` is a column vector. You can get a row vector of shape `(1, 4)` by using `np.expand_dims(a, 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways:

```
In [1]: x=np.arange(4); x
Out[1]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

`reshape` is a good function/method to learn well:

```
In [2]: x.reshape(-1,1)
Out[2]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3]])
In [4]: x.reshape(1,-1)
Out[4]: array([[0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

Many experienced users like to `np.newaxis/None` indexing:

```
In [5]: x[:,None]
Out[5]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3]])
In [6]: x[None,:]
Out[6]: array([[0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

Functions like `expand_dims` use `reshape` - look at its code:

```
In [8]: np.expand_dims(x,1)
Out[8]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Another:

```
In [9]: np.atleast_2d(x)
Out[9]: array([[0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

And if making the array from 'scratch', `ndmin` can be used:

```
In [10]: np.array(x, ndmin=2)
Out[10]: array([[0, 1, 2, 3]])
```

Because leading dimensions are "outermost" (for C order), a (1,4) shape is in some sense more "natural" for `numpy` than (4,1).